# Adding a strong name / signature to an outside DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, strongname

We're signing our library but one of our external dependencies is itself not signed, giving us the following error:

`Referenced assembly 'ManyConsole' does not have a strong name`

We get the `ManyConsole` package (a great one BTW!) via Nuget but are ok with a non-Nuget orphan that is signed by us. In fact, we could very well sign it with the same key as our own app but it's not clear how we can sign an "outside" DLL.

Comment: Why are you signing your library? *shiver*

Answer (score 2):

You could either:

- [Load the assembly dynamically](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/187788/Dynamically-Loading-NET-Assemblies-using-Interface)
- [Sign the third-party assembly](https://buffered.io/posts/.net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/) (involves disassembling it first)

Comment: Second link dead

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a 3rd party NuGet package that was not signed but my project required all assemblies to be signed.

I installed the NuGet package [StrongNameSigner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Brutal.Dev.StrongNameSigner/) which automatically signs all non-signed assemblies. This worked great. Easy to setup, just install the package, nothing to configure. Works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post, especially the answer from x0n, will help. It did help me.

[Strongly naming a 3rd party assembly - Could not load file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943091/strongly-naming-a-3rd-party-assembly-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/16512453#comment30683435_16512453)

Answer (score 0):

We can follow the below steps to sign an external DLL when we do not have the source code:

1. Use ILDASM to generate the IL code from the DLL as follows:
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ildasm.exe" /all /out=<NameOfAssembly>.il <NameOfAssembly>.dll
2. Generate key file & public key file using SN utility as follows:
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\sn.exe" -p <NameOfKeyFile>.snk <NameOfKeyFile>.pub
3. Now, if the target assembly depends on another assembly (say "Target.dll" depends on "Another.dll") then first we need to perform step (1) for both the DLLs.
4. Use ILASM to generate signed assembly as follows:
   "C:\WIndows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe" /dll /key=<NameOfKeyFile>.snk <NameOfAssembly>.il
5. Get the public key from <NameOfKeyFile>.pub as follows:
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\sn.exe" -tp <NameOfKeyFile>.pub.
6. Before generating signed assembly for "Target.dll". We have to set the public key in "Target.il". So open "Target.il" and search for ".assembly extern". You may encounter many such lines so pick the one which contains something like ".assembly extern /* <Number> */ Another". Add the public token from previous step in ".assembly extern" section as follows:

   .assembly extern /* <Number> */ Another
   {
   .publickeytoken = (<publicKeyToken> )
   .ver 0:3:0:0
   }

Note: Say, public token is "3e4e219a61a9d384" then in the above section, it should be represented as "3E 4E 21 9A 61 A9 D3 84"

7. Now, you can generate signed "Target.dll" & "Another.dll".
8. Sometimes, there may be "InternalsVisibleTo" attribute used inside "Another.dll" & exposed to "Target.dll". This means that internal methods / properties in "Another.dll" generally accessible within "Another.dll" is also accessible to "Target.dll".

"InternalsVisibleTo" is defined as follows in "AssemblyInfo.cs" when assembly is unsigned:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Target")]
```

"InternalsVisibleTo" is defined as follows in "AssemblyInfo.cs" when assembly is signed:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Target, PublicKey=&lt;PublicKey&gt;")]
```

Therefore, in this case, you have to inject the public key in this section too. To locate this section, search by "InternalsVisibleTo" in "Another.il" pointing to "Target.dll". Here, you shall find the hex representation of the string parameter value "Target" which is to be replaced carefully by the hex representation of new string parameter value "Target, PublicKey=<PublicKey>"

9. Now generate signed "Another.dll" after injecting public key into InternalsVisibleTo attribute.

Comment: If you find difficulty in generating hex representation for "Target, PublicKey=&lt;PublicKey&gt;" then you can create a simple assembly & add this in AssemblyInfo.cs, generate IL and extract the hex code.