# Adding a strong name to 3rd party assembly break on deployment?

Tags: c#, .net, strongname

I am developing a plugin that uses some third party assemblies. My product is strongly named. The referenced assembly is not which of course generates an error.

There is plenty of information available on how to strongly name a third party assembly. If you got here looking for "how to" look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943091/strongly-naming-a-3rd-party-assembly-could-not-load-file-or-assembly) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331520/how-to-fix-referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name-error).

However my question is not how but **what** will happen.

My plugin during development has a reference to the third party assemblies but when packaged for release those assemblies are **NOT** included as it is a guarantee the target machine already has those assemblies.

However the assemblies will NOT be signed on the target machine.

This will cause my plugin to throw an exception won't it or is this just a VS compile time issue to do with needed debug symbols? I should think not and that my plugin will fail....except that I read if I switched from early binding to late and loaded the third party assembly dynamically it won't be a problem so in a release scenario is the early binding strong name check enforced?

Thanks